# Difference between надо and нужен

Tags: перевод

In my textbook the word надо is translated into: "It is needed" and нужен: "needed". As russian speaker. When do you use these two words, are there any nuances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `надо` is more colloquial than `нужен`.

To say **[somebody] needs [something]** you use the two words in such a way: **[somebody in the Dat. case] надо/нужен [something in the Nom. case]**. Note, `надо` never changes its form, but `нужен` must agree in number and gender with the subject of the sentence, that is the part which is in the Nominative case. For example:

> I need a pencil.
>
> Мне надо карандаш.
>
> Мне нужен карандаш.

.

> Oleg needs a pen.
>
> Олегу надо ручка.
>
> Олегу нужна ручка.

Still, in sentences like **[somebody] needs [something]**, `нужен` is used more often.

There is another way to use the two words, it is when you want to say **[somebody] needs [to do something]**. In this case, `нужен` is used in the neuter gender, `нужно`, and both words are absolutely interchangeable. The construction is like this: **[somebody in the Dat. case] надо/нужно [infinitive phrase]**. For example:

> I need to go.
>
> Мне надо/нужно уходить.

.

> You need to see that.
>
> Вам надо/нужно это увидеть.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't say "мне надо карандаш", "надо" is always about some action.

Both words are OK if you talk about some action, "надо сходить в магазин"/"нужно сходить в магазин", but then "нужно" is more formal.

If you need something (or someone), it will always be "нужен": "мне нужен карандаш", "чтобы решить проблему, нам нужен Вася", "я никому не нужен, пойду повешусь"

Comment: "Мне надо VERB карандаш" and “Олегу надо VERB ручку" are correct. “Олегу надо ручку" is more colloquial. But "Олегу надо ручка" sounds like said by guest worker. "Мне надо карандаш" - it is only a spoken language, and the one who says that, knows that this is incorrect to say so.

Answer (score 6):

"**Надо**" (нужно) mainly combines with **verbs** (infinitives):

```
это надо/нужно сделать - it needs to be done,
```

while **"нужен"** (м.р.) combines with (masculine) **nouns**:

```
 нужен нож - a knife is needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

*Нужный* is an *adjective* meaning "needed", "required", "necessary".

*Нужен / Нужна* is a *short adjective* made of the full form *нужный*. Short adjectives often are the part of predicative (e.g. "Я им нужен") but they are still *adjectives*.

*Нужно / Надо* are purely impersonate constructions like, say, Spanish *hay que*. The closest English equivalent would be "It is needed". The difference between *надо* and *нужно* is very, very slight. You may simply ignore it for a moment.

P.S. Technically, *нужно* is the neuter gender of the short adjective *нужен / нужна* but in the vast majority of cases *нужно* stands for an impersonate, not for an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The same like "we need" vs "he is needed (for something)"